# Christmas and Anouka version of my site

Tags: php

with the holiday (anouka and Christmas) i wanted to show different version of my site.

i want to change the images, css etc...

is there a very quick to do so? or special techniques?

my site is in php and i use apache

Comment: Then why don't you just change the images, css, etc., and then restore them from source control later?

Comment: use sprites, easy and fast

Comment: I've you've got your site set up perfectly you just change the .css and the links to the images and you're set, but you question-style suggests that you probably need more help. Unfortunately, we can only give that help if you give us some more info

Comment: WOW i guess people don't appreciate the holidays

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<?php
$christmas = "12-25";
$todays_date = date("m-d");
if($todays_date == $christmas) {
   // Load a different stylesheet
} else {
   // Load the stylesheet for the rest of the yeat
}
?>
```

This will load a different stylesheet every year on Christmas day. It can be changed to any other date by changing the `$christmas` variable. I think this is what you're looking for...